# How do you specialize constants using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I want to return a different constant for each different type that is used for the templated class.

For example, when the class is

Stack< int > I want the constant
*EMPTY = -99*

when the class is Stack< char > I want the constant EMPTY to be '\0'.

So far I have been searching for the syntax for how to explicitly specialize variables and have no idea where to start looking for this.

A simple code example would be amazing, as this issue has been bugging me for a while.

What I have so far (without constants) is:

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
private:
       T* items_;
        //EMPTY constant here

public:

    Stack();

    ~Stack();

    void push(T value);

    T pop();
};
```

Comment: Would a function returning a constant value be sufficient? My experience is that sometimes ordinary "constants" make trouble even in non-templated classes.

Comment: Ya that would be fine, I've been trying that and having issues. But all suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
private:
       T* items_;
       static T EMPTY;

public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();

    void push(T value);
    T pop();
};

extern template<> int Stack<int>::EMPTY;
extern template<> char Stack<char>::EMPTY;
```

Then in a cpp file:

```
template<> int Stack<int>::EMPTY = -99;
template<> char Stack<char>::EMPTY = '\0';
```

Note depending on usage this will limit the types you can instantiate your template with.

Comment: This is giving me the error: multiple definition of 'Stack<int>'

Comment: The standard prohibits specialising a template if you specialised a member before for the same template parameters. So if you want to have stack specialised for int then declare class specialisation first and then define the static (in a cpp file) - that's just normal template specialisation

Comment: Another possible source of the error is that I have put empty definitions for the ctor and dtor which you did not have. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sadly neither this or the next answer will compile for me. The code you wrote looks perfectly logical to me, yet GCC will just not stop complaining about multiple definitions.

Comment: CMakeFiles\bonus_ass2.dir/objects.a(a2_dynamic_stack.cpp.obj):a2_dynamic_stack.cpp:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `DynamicStack<int>::EMPTY'
CMakeFiles\bonus_ass2.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.data+0x0): first defined here
CMakeFiles\bonus_ass2.dir/objects.a(a2_dynamic_stack.cpp.obj): In function `_tcf_0':

Comment: I've edited the answer, can you try that. (I have not run it through a compiler, but I think the problem is you put the definitions for statics in a header file)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider whether you want this to be part of your stack, or rather factor it out to a general [traits](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442) class. Depending on what you do, it might be useful for other data structures.

```
template<typename T>
struct traits
{
    static T empty;
};
template<> int traits<int>::empty = 99;
template<> char traits<char>::empty = 0;


template<class T>
class Stack 
{
public:
    Stack()
    {
        T t = traits<T>::empty; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack<int>(); 
    Stack<char>(); 
}
```